# Free of charge Robot Magazine, Journal, Newsletter or similar

Tags: publications

What free of charge Robot Magazine, Journal, Newsletter or similar publication are available?

Either geared toward technical professionals or the general public.

Comment: Are you wanting physical printed magazines? Or online ones as well? (I'm asking because I have a list of great online ones).

Comment: Both versions are great. Please advise. Many thanks

Comment: I personally think this should be taken off hold. It does not ask which magazines are BEST (opinion) it just asks for magazines. I think it would be nice to have this information on this website. To say "this is a magazine about robotics" is a fact, not opinion.

Comment: Anyways, here are some that I frequent, some of which are strictly robotics, other are just general technology, but cover robotics frequently: Gizmag, Hack A Day, Popular Science, Popular Mechanics, Robohub, IEEE Spectrum (Robotics), ROS Robotics News, ScienceDaily: Robot News, Singularity hub

Comment: Sadly [List questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/138432) are rarely of lasting value either, since it is unusual for them to receive enough attention to be kept up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the open access robotics journals (free access)

1) [International Journal of Advanced Robotic Systems](http://www.intechopen.com/journals/international_journal_of_advanced_robotic_systems)

[image: International Journal of Advanced Robotic Systems]

2) [Robotics: Science and Systems](http://www.roboticsproceedings.org/)

[image: Robotics: Science and Systems]